# Easy HTTPS to PHP script

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ssl, https

here is my scenario:

I have a website with php, mySQL. I have a software application that has a login screen and sends usernames and passwords over the web by http:

```
    public String GetWebPageSource(String pURL)
    {

        try
        {


            byte[] vReceivedBytes = null;
            using (System.Net.WebClient vWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                vReceivedBytes = vWebClient.DownloadData(pURL);
            }
            int vBomLen = 3;
            byte[] vStrippedBytes = new byte[vReceivedBytes.Length - vBomLen];
            Array.Copy(vReceivedBytes, vBomLen, vStrippedBytes, 0, vReceivedBytes.Length - vBomLen);

            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(vStrippedBytes);



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

So to send a username and password I would write:

GetWebPageSource("http://mywebsite.com/Login.php?username=stackoverflow&password=iscool")

and the php file would spit out some text saying whether the password is accepted or denied.

However this is NOT secure. So I want to make it secure... https. How easy is it to integrate https? How much will the code change? How much do I have to handle? What is transparent to me. Do I have to check if a cookie already exists and if not write the methods for authentication or is there librarys already provided that will do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For programming point of view, calling an php script using http or https doesn't make any difference. It's just a matter of configuring apache (or any other web server) to handle https (most notably obtaining a certificate).

Comment: So I can you https:// path instead  of http when making the request. How will the cookie be managed? What's it's lifetime... I would hate for the server to have to reauthenticate every time I make a GetWebPageSource call. What is the performance hit on the server from using SSL? So to confirm do I not need to modify this code? If I configure the keys etc on the server end will it all be transparent to me?

Comment: Yes, once you've gotten your web server configured properly, it should listen to both http and https requests. You probably won't have to modify the code much, but it's good practice to "force" https for your authentication page. I don't know the best practice for this, (probably some sort of redirect) but I'm sure you'll find a bunch of discussions online.

Comment: I'm not sure how session handling works with C#, but generally most languages like PHP handle sessions rather transparently. You can just call a function (start_session) and then add values such as the login username to a global session array. Then, other pages/scripts just need to check the array to make sure you're logged in. (I mention PHP because it's in your title. Is the "back-end" in PHP?)

Comment: Finally, I've read recently that a number of sites (e.g. github) are going "SSL-only" because of security concerns. Nowadays, there is really no performance hit to the server for using SSL.

Comment: For testing purposes, most web servers will have a self-signed certificate for SSL. You can use that in the meantime while testing your application. In general, you'll have to bypass the certificate check or else your app may not connect to the server. Later on, you can use a signed certificate obtained by a certificate authority company such as Verisign, or perhaps GoDaddy or Comodo.

Comment: I am indeed using a PHP backend. Does HTTPS mean I can send passwords without bothering to apply an encryption algorithm at the login screen or should I still apply one? Thank you for your help. I look forward to implementing my solution in the coming weeks

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you'll want to configure the web server to use TLS/SSL. It doesn't really matter which server-side language you're using for your site.

In general, the server side scripts will set a cookie/session on successful authentication, and then just check the cookie or session data for any actions that require an authenticated user. With a properly configured server, the encryption of the authentication is handled automatically by the server and the client's browser.

I also recommend using a debugging proxy and watching the requests/responses to and from the server during the authentication steps. This'll show you whether or not you actually have a secure connection.

Comment: Debugging proxy? Where can I get one of those? :) Please see my comment on sfk's post

Comment: Personally, I love Charles, which is a shareware but has a decent trial. Basically, when you launch the app it automatically "records" all of the requests and responses to/from your browser or other apps that use HTTP. It's really useful for debugging AJAX back-ends, iPhone apps, etc. In your case, you'll be able to verify whether or not your authentication is encrypted by looking at the requests to your auth script and seeing the garbled request body.